# How to extract an attribute in jsoup

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing

How do I extract the `url = ""` part from the following XML-Tag. I am using `Jsoup`, in Android.

```
<enclosure type="image/jpg" url="EXTRACT THIS" length="123456" />
```

See my code:

```
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            // Get all <item> tags.
            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
            int length = nl.getLength();


            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                Node currentNode = nl.item(i);
                RSSItem _item = new RSSItem();

                NodeList nchild = currentNode.getChildNodes();
                int clength = nchild.getLength();

                // Get the required elements from each Item
                for (int j = 0; j < clength; j = j + 1) {

                    Node thisNode = nchild.item(j);
                    String theString = null;
                    String nodeName = thisNode.getNodeName();

                    //NodeList test = nchild.item(j).getChildNodes();

                    if(j<=3){
                        theString = nchild.item(j).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                    }
                    if("enclosure".equals(nodeName)){
                        //HAVE TO GET URL HERE from ATTRIBUTE:  
                    }
```

This is the XML:

```
view-source:http://www.skysports.com/rss/0,20514,11661,00.xml
```

Comment: I already looked at this link. It didn't help. I am new to Android

Answer (score 1):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(link).get();
        Elements elements= doc
                .getElementsByTag("enclosure");
    for(int i=0;i<elements.getsize();i++){
        String url=elements.get(i).attr("href");}
```

You search by Tag Name and it will get elements That have Tag You Entered ..
i Use get(0) to indicate that it may be first element of your link .. OR .. may be It is The only element .. Use index as You see its order in link ..
attr : To get attribute of in that element 
It`s Return String ..

Good luck :)

Comment: I have See Your Link .. You Could Do For Loop by .get(index)

Comment: I am parsing one element at a time.